# PHP + CSS: Output Options Framework Content

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Two questions from a coding ub3r n00b...

Firstly, I'm using the *Options Framework Theme by Devin Price* and just wanting to know how would I output the background property in the `<head>` section of my `header.php` file, from the *Theme Options* page **only if** the user has uploaded an image or chosen a color for this?

My `options.php`:

```
$options[] = array(
    'name' =>  __('Background', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('Add a background.', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'id' => 'background-one',
    'std' => $background_defaults,
    'type' => 'background' );
```

My `Theme Options` page:

[image]

My `header.php`:

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php $background = of_get_option('background-one');
    echo 'body {';
        if ($background['color']) {   
        echo '
        background: ' .$background['color']. ';';
        }

        if ($background['image']) {
        echo '
        background: url('.$background['image']. ') ';
            echo ''.$background['repeat']. ' ';
            echo ''.$background['position']. ' ';
            echo ''.$background['attachment']. ';';
        } 
    echo '
    }';
?>
</style>
```

Which works perfectly fine in the front-end of my site, displaying the CSS as:

```
body {
    background: #8224e3;
    background: url(images/bg03.gif) repeat top left fixed;
}
```

But if the user hasn't chosen a colour or image as a background through the *Theme Options* page, the source code will output:

```
body {
}
```

How would I be able to remove the above CSS if the user hasn't chosen a background?

From what I gather, an `if` statement needs to be created but I don't how to write this up correctly as I'm fairly new to php.

---

Secondly, how would I be able to set a default background image in the framework?

My `options.php`:

```
// Background Defaults
    $background_defaults = array(
        'color' => '',
        'image' => '',
        'repeat' => 'no-repeat',
        'position' => 'top left',
        'attachment' => 'fixed' );
```

Thanks

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question but a support request for the *Options Framework Theme by Devin Price*. Please contact the software vendor for your support options.

Comment: Just move the `echo "body{` to within an if statement, such that it only outputs if the background variables you require are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move a few things to be within an if statement, like so:

```
<?php 
    $background = of_get_option('background-one');
    if ($background['color'] || $background['image']) {
        echo '<style type="text/css" >';
        echo 'body {';
        if ($background['color']) {   
            echo '
            background: ' .$background['color']. ';';
        }

        if ($background['image']) {
            echo '
            background: url('.$background['image']. ') ';
            echo ''.$background['repeat']. ' ';
            echo ''.$background['position']. ' ';
            echo ''.$background['attachment']. ';';
        } 
        echo '
        }';
        echo '</style>';
    }
?>
```

And, for your second question, simply make the following change:

```
// Set up a default image
// NOTE: This is designed for the image to be located in your theme folder, inside an images folder
$default = get_bloginfo("template_url") . 'images/default.jpg';
// Background Defaults
$background_defaults = array(
    'color' => '',
    'image' => $default,
    'repeat' => 'no-repeat',
    'position' => 'top left',
    'attachment' => 'fixed' );
```

Comment: Thank you @cale_b, just what I was after.

Any ideas on the second part?

Comment: Bravo, all the best cale_b.